# Cassini 's and Pioneers RTG power output datafile

Tags: data

I'd like to have access to the datafile of the electrical output of the RTG (Radioisotope Thermoelectric Generator) of  the Pioneer's and Cassini missions, as can be seen in the figures 1 of the papers of [Anderson,2002](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/gr-qc/pdf/0107/0107022v3.pdf) and [Peter S. Cooper, publ 2009](http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.4248).
I know that I can grab the aprox values  directly from the published graphs with the help of software, but accessing the original data is better.
I g-searched but I did not found them.
Can someone give advice, pls?

The question is specific but the answers can say more about the difficulties and solutions of accessing scientific data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard thing to do is contact the author(s) and ask.

- Be polite--this person will have to take some time out of their "real" work to help you.
- Introduce yourself (include any institutional affiliation than may lend you legitimacy).
- Explain *why* you are interested and what you hope to *do* with the data.

Most publications and the arXiv indicate the "corresponding author", and this is probably the person to try first.

Be aware that some data may be covered by agreements to not make it public until after publication (or some arbitrary publication window typically on order of one year).